# Confirming a reported vulnerability in ZAP (SQL Injection authentication bypass)

Tags: sql-injection, zap, false-positive

I need to manually confirm. the following... how do i go about it?

I have tried putting the parameter as the login name and the ZAP AND 1=1-- as the password in the form....this doesn't work. Do i even use the login form or do i use the URL and craft a special URL to attack this successfully?

URL:    https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/scripts/userscripts/UserScript.pl?function=commitmodifyirisagent

Method: POST

Parameter:  site

Attack  ZAP AND 1=1 --

Answer (score 1):

Why not reproducing the attack using the URL supplied by Zap? You can see in Zap's report what is the suspicious URL, and there is also an evidence.

Comment: Because the URL is just the base URL, its not crafted to take advantage of the vulnerability.  I need to know how to craft the URL to do so.

Comment: I think you can get all the HTTP messages from Zap, look like this will give you also the one with SQL injection: `<zap-url>/JSON/core/view/messages/?zapapiformat=JSON&formMethod=GET&baseurl=&start=&count=`